# how do I get rid of the caps-lock key on windows XP?

Tags: windows-xp, capslock

I'm stuck on an XP machine at work, and I really hate the cap-lock key. In OSX, Linux, and Vista, I have always been able to map it to another ctrl (as it should be in any sane world).

However, in XP, I haven't find a way to do this this that doesn't involve editing resource files...

does anyone have a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

[This site](http://johnhaller.com/jh/useful_stuff/disable_caps_lock/) gives some registry files which can be used to disable the caps lock key or to repurpose it for something else.

Works for XP and also worked on Win7 when I got my new laptop.  I hate the caps lock key, especially on machines without a half height key for it.

Comment: +1 for tweaks that don't involve additional programs.

Answer (score 0):

Try [KeyTweak](http://majorgeeks.com/KeyTweak_d4161.html):

> KeyTweak is a simple utility that allows users to redefine their keyboard input signals. The functionality is made possible by a registry value first documented in Windows 2000, but also present in Windows NT 4.0. and included in XP, Vista and Windows 7.